# Retrieving multiple JSON objects from a database results in Express error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, handlebars.js

I am retrieving a JSON object from an external database using a private api key. I am using express as my HTTP. I am building a nutrition app that gathers a list of foods given by an input from the UI. When more than one food object is returned, the error occurs that I cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. My goal is to have a drop down of list of foods when a user types in a food.

I've tried limiting only one food object output; no error occurs. I've tried setting the food objects into separate object arrays and the error still persists. I've made sure to use return to catch only one response if previous  results were to occur to prevent other express routing from executing. Not sure where the add image button here is, but here is an example of what outputs in fetchFoods.js:

```
{ foodName: 'ARMADILLO EGGS, UPC: 732170002859',
  foodNum: '45220998' }
{ foodName: 'ARMADILLO EGGS, UPC: 732170003856',
  foodNum: '45201506' }
{ foodName: 'ARTESANIA, TOASTED ALMOND EGG NOUGHT, UPC: 815961010209',
  foodNum: '45161494' }
...
```

However, when executing from index.js, that's where the error occurs. When referring to errors I've mentioned, that's only when fetchFoods.js is executed at index.js. Otherwise, I am able to output multiple food objects from the database directly from the fetchFoods.js file.

```
_http_outgoing.js:482
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)
```

In terms of limiting one food result, no error occurs from either executing from fetchFoods.js or index.js. I think my problem lies within my express configuration. I'm able to view the food result (only if limited to one) in my terminal and my console but not if there more than one.

### Edit

This is the original JSON object:

```
list": {
"q": "eggs",
"sr": "1",
"ds": "any",
"start": 0,
"end": 25,
"total": 1956,
"group": "",
"sort": "n",
"item": [
{
"offset": 0,
"group": "Branded Food Products Database",
"name": "AHOLD, DEVILED EGG POTATO SALAD, UPC: 688267141584",
"ndbno": "45044170",
"ds": "LI",
"manu": "Ahold USA, Inc."
},
```

profile.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="icon" href="/img/app_logo.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
        <title>Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-content">
            {{>header}}

            <p>{{title}}</p>
            <p>{{greeting}}</p>

            <form>
                <input placeholder="Search for foods">
                <button>Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>       

        {{>footer}}
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
app.get('/fetchFoods', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.query.food){
        return res.send({
            error: 'You must provide a food!'
        });
    }
    next();
     fetchFoods(req.query.food, (error, {foodName, foodNum} = {}) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.send({error});
        } else {
            return res.send({
                foodName,
                foodNum
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

app.js

```
const foodForm = document.querySelector('form');
const search = document.querySelector('input');

foodForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    console.log('testing');
    e.preventDefault();

    const food = search.value;

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/fetchFoods?food=' + food).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((data) => {
            if (data.error) {
                console.log(data.error);
            } else {
                console.log(data.foodName);
                console.log(data.foodNum);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
        });
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

fetchFoods.js

```
const request = require('request');


const fetchFoods = (food, callback) => {
    const url = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?format=json&q=' + encodeURIComponent(food) + '&sort=n&max=25&offset=0&api_key=###';

    request({url:url, json:true}, (error, {body}) => {

        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to USDA database!', undefined);
        } else if (body.errors) {
            callback(body.errors.error[0].message);
        }

        var foodItem = body.list.item;

        for (var i = 0; i < foodItem.length; i++){          
            callback(undefined, {
                foodName: foodItem[i].name,
                foodNum: foodItem[i].ndbno
            });  
        }        
    });
};

fetchFoods('eggs', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    } else {
        return console.log(data);
    }
});

module.exports = fetchFoods;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nutrition-app-heroku",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js -e js,hbs",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js -e js,hbs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hbs": "^4.0.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.7",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.4",
    "mustache": "^3.0.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "validator": "^11.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are calling res.send multiple timesm, you can only send once.

I think the error is here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foodItem.length; i++){          
    callback(undefined, {
             foodName: foodItem[i].name,
             foodNum: foodItem[i].ndbno
    });  
}
```

You should send back the object:

```
callback(undefined, foodItem);
```

Then send the foodItems to the client:

```
fetchFoods(req.query.food, (error, foodItems) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.send({error});
        } else {
            res.send(foodItems);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this method before. I'm specifically targeting name and ndbno from the JSON list, thus for foodName and foodNum. Both objects are successfully retrieved when I customize fetchFoods.js to only take the first one object from the results. However, when I loop thru the JSON list and try to request multiple results and execute from index.js; that is when it's an issue. By the way, with your suggested change, the error in my console shows: profile:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (profile.hbs).

Answer (score 0):

Comment all the res.sends in the index.js file and write console.log('sth') so that you should know which block of code is being executed. This happens when the server for some reason executes two res methods (i.e sends two responses) at the same time. Because of this express has to set the headers again which is you know not how its supposed to be. In a usual HTTP request response cycle, a client sends a request to the server, the server processes that request and sends a response and thats it.

You have used a for loop in the fetch foods function inside which is the callback function. So for each loop iteration, the callback gets called again and the browser has to send a response again. That should be it. Try that and tell if it works. I had an encounter with this set headers error a lot and thats the only reason I have found.

Comment: Tried that, commented all res.sends in my index.js file. Same error. What's interesting is that when uncommenting fetchFoods() from fetchFoods.js, The command line terminal shows the json list of foods when index.js is executed. When clicking on the button on my web page, that's when 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' comes up. I added a catch block on app.js and the console shows: 
Error Reading data SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
I checked the network, all files related to being executed are at a 200 status.

Comment: By the way, by comment all res.sends in my index.js, I'm only referring to /fetchFoods route. There are other routes in the index.js file, which has res.sends. Since other routes are unaffected during fetchFoods() inside /fetchFoods, I felt it was unecessary to mention. But I'll bring it up for the sake of clarification.